# Skip-gram with Word2Vec not working properly

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I am trying to build a word2vec  similarity dictionary. I was able to build one dictionary but the similarities are not being populated correctly. Am I missing anything in my code?

**Input sample data  Text**

```
TAK PO LUN UNIT 3 15/F WAYSON COMMERCIAL G 28 CONNAUGHT RD WEST SHEUNG WAN
- EDDY SUSANTO YAHYA ROOM 1503-05 WESTERN CENTRE 40-50 DES VOEUX W. SHEUNG WAN
DNA FINANCIAL SYSTEMS INC UNIT 10 19F WAYSON COMMERCIAL 28 CONNAUGHT RD SHEUNG WAN
G/F 60 PO HING FONG SHEUNG WAN
10B CENTRAL MANSION 270 QUEENS RD CENTRAL SHEUNG WAN
AKAMAI INTERNATIONAL BV C/O IADVANTAGE 28/F OF MEGA I-ADVANTAGE 399 CHAI WAN RD CHAI WAN HONG KO HONG KONG
VICTORIA CHAN F/5E 1-3 FLEMING RD WANCHI WAN CHAI
HISTREND 365 5/F FOO TAK BUILDING 365 HENNESSY RD WAN CHAI H WAN CHAI
ROOM 1201 12F CHINACHEM JOHNSO PLAZA 178 186 JOHNSTON RD WAN CHAI
LUEN WO BUILDING 339 HENNESSY RD 9 FLOOR WAN CHAI HONG KONG
```

**My code:**

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora,similarities,models
class AccCorpus(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.path = ''

   def __iter__(self):
       for sentence in data["Adj_Addr"]:
           yield [word.lower() for word in sentence.split()]

   def build_corpus():
       model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(alpha=0.05, min_alpha=0.05,window=2,sg=1)
       sentences = AccCorpus()
       model.build_vocab(sentences)
       for epoch in range(1):
           model.train(sentences,total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
           model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate
           model.min_alpha = model.alpha  # fix the learning rate, no decay

       model_name = "word2vec_model"
       model.save(model_name)
       return model

model=build_corpus()
```

**My results:**

```
model.most_similar("wan")
[('want', 0.6867533922195435),
 ('puiwan', 0.6323356032371521),
 ('wan.', 0.6132887005805969),
 ('wanstreet', 0.5945449471473694),
 ('aupuiwan', 0.594132661819458),
 ('futan', 0.5883135199546814),
 ('fotan', 0.5817855000495911),
 ('shanmei', 0.5807071924209595),
 ('30-33', 0.5789132118225098),
 ('61-63au', 0.5711270570755005)]
```

Here are my expected outputs for the similarity: **sheungwan, wanchai, chaiwan**. I am guessing my skipgrams are not working properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't change `alpha` or `min_alpha` from the defaults. Don't call `train()` more than once or try to manage `alpha` yourself. Do make sure you've got a lot of good data that's pre-processed into word-tokens in a sensible way. Do enable logging and make sure all the steps are generating sensible output showing progress. Start with a working example on some similar dataset and only change parameters (like `window`) if you're sure it's helping improve against baseline results.

Comment: @gojomo, Has it something do with sg parameter

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested in the comments, there's no need to tweak `alpha` and other internal parameters, unless you're sure it's necessary (in your case it's not, most probably).

You're getting a lot of extra results because it's in your data somewhere. I don't know what `Adj_Addr` is, but it's not just the text you provided: `puiwan`, `futan`, `fotan`, ... - none of this is in the text above.

Here's the clean test that works just as you want it to work (I left only relevant part, feel free to add `sg=1` - works as well):

```py
import gensim

text = """TAK PO LUN UNIT 3 15/F WAYSON COMMERCIAL G 28 CONNAUGHT RD WEST SHEUNG WAN
- EDDY SUSANTO YAHYA ROOM 1503-05 WESTERN CENTRE 40-50 DES VOEUX W. SHEUNG WAN
DNA FINANCIAL SYSTEMS INC UNIT 10 19F WAYSON COMMERCIAL 28 CONNAUGHT RD SHEUNG WAN
G/F 60 PO HING FONG SHEUNG WAN
10B CENTRAL MANSION 270 QUEENS RD CENTRAL SHEUNG WAN
AKAMAI INTERNATIONAL BV C/O IADVANTAGE 28/F OF MEGA I-ADVANTAGE 399 CHAI WAN RD CHAI WAN HONG KO HONG KONG
VICTORIA CHAN F/5E 1-3 FLEMING RD WANCHI WAN CHAI
HISTREND 365 5/F FOO TAK BUILDING 365 HENNESSY RD WAN CHAI H WAN CHAI
ROOM 1201 12F CHINACHEM JOHNSO PLAZA 178 186 JOHNSTON RD WAN CHAI
LUEN WO BUILDING 339 HENNESSY RD 9 FLOOR WAN CHAI HONG KONG"""

sentences = text.split('\n')

class AccCorpus(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.path = ''

  def __iter__(self):
    for sentence in sentences:
      yield [word.lower() for word in sentence.split()]

def build_corpus():
  model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec()
  sentences = AccCorpus()
  model.build_vocab(sentences)
  model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
  return model

model = build_corpus()
print(model.most_similar("wan"))
```

The result is:

```
[('chai', 0.04687393456697464), ('rd', -0.03181878849864006), ('sheung', -0.06769674271345139)]
```